# Flutter App shows a Blank screen when clicking on Notification from the background

Tags: flutter, notifications, just-audio, flutter-local-notification

i used **flutter_local_notifications**, **just_audio** and **just_audio_background** to show notification controller

problem is when I press the notification when the app is in the background, the application opens to a blank screen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.